# Snapping of walls and floors

Tags: modeling

So I am building a house right now, or trying to, and I've made the floor, walls, and doorway. The only trouble I seem to be having so far is how they all fit together. Is there a way to make these snap together?
[image]

Comment: You seem to have a separate object for every wall. Is there a reason for this? What are you intending to do with the model? Please upload your file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: You must use boolean modifier to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You can activate the *Snap* option to make the vertices of your walls stick together, it will also work in *Edit* mode. As Yash said, you could also use a *Boolean* modifier to merge some walls, but it won't always give good result. But as AzulShiva said, maybe the best is to model your walls within only one object, it will simplify your work, unless you have a very particular reason to separate your walls.

[image]

Comment: thanks guys your really helped me out i couldnt figure that out for the life of me lol.

Comment: @Lane you must accept the answer by click the right(✔) icon located below voting when you are satisfied with the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Moonboots, and would just add that if you're using Snap in Edit Mode, then having Snap set to 'Vertex' and 'Active', selecting all the vertices you want to transform, with your desired source vertex selected last to make it active, and then hovering over the target, yields the most predictable results. I almost never have my Snap set to anything else.